# Here - Filtering wrong waypoints

Tags: here-api

When I send my waypoints to the API, I know some points are wrong (because they are recovered by a GPS Phone and It’s not precise).

So some point are outside of the real road, and the Here's API thinks it’s a correct value and decides to calculate a route passing by this point.

For example (capture) :

[image: capture of route]

The point 1 / 2 are correct. But the point 3 is positioning outside of the road (on the another road). 
The point 4 / 5 are correct.

The correct Way is green arrow but the API return another route to pass on the point 4 :

[image: capture of here result]

My question is, how I can bypass waypoints how are outside the initial road ? Your API are certainly an algorithm to fix wrong waypoints ?

I trying add the **generalizationtolerances** and **TransitRadiusparams**... but nothing works.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Which Here API are you using? Please provide the api along with the waypoints sequence for us to help you better. Also, if you are using Routing API then try RME(Route Match Extension) API to see if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through Here RME API. You can try the api using the demo example provided in https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/v3/rme_basic(login with Here credentials). 
The below input was used where waypoint 3 is wrong.
SEQNR, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE
0, 49.35921, 2.42461
1, 49.3593, 2.42436
2, 49.36088, 2.42494
3, 49.36099, 2.42408
4, 49.36039, 2.42303
5, 49.3621, 2.42184

```
https://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest;car;traffic:disabled&app_id=xxxx&app_code=yyyy
```

[image]